# Select Laravel eloquent data where created_at matched from a date array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `CLICK` model that contains click information of users.

I want to get click data where specific date matched.

Like,

`$date = ['09/08/2022', '09/16/2022', '03/08/2022']`

I want that clicks which `created_at` are match with one element of `$date` array.

Laravel has `->whereIn()` eloquent function to do almost same task, but in my case `created_at` and `$date` array element does not has same date format.

Note that: it is not `->whereBetween()`, I want to match specific date contains in a `$date` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :)

```
 $arr = ['07/07/2022', '07/08/2022', '07/09/2022'];
 $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m/%d/%Y') IN('" . join("','", $arr) . "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `created_at` is a timestamp:

You can chain `orWhereRaw()`s with `LEFT()`:

```php
$myQuery
    ->whereRaw("LEFT(created_at, 10) = '2022-09-08'")
    ->orWhereRaw("LEFT(created_at, 10) = '2022-09-16'")
    ->orWhereRaw("LEFT(created_at, 10) = '2022-08-03'")
    ...
```

Comment: `$date` array is demo data, date may contains variable size dates. 
`$date = ['09/08/2022', '09/16/2022', '03/08/2022',.....,...,....,....,....]` what should I do that time? a for each loop? it may be gonna bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, you can do a for loop.

Comment: okey. i will check